# Bootstrap Contact Form Checkbox PHP Ajax Email not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email, contact-form

searched already the forum about this, found solutions but still haven't nailed it yet.

I have a contact form in a bootstrap form which I customnized with a checkbox. The contact form works, just the value of the checkboxes (what the vistiors ticks) are not send (or appearing) in the email.

So far it looks like this:

**HTML**:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ihr Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ihre Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Bitte geben Sie Ihre E-Mail ein.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Ihre Telefonnummer (optional)" id="phone" >
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea type="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Ihre Adresse (optional)" id="address"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ihre Sozialversicherungsnummer (optional)" id="socialnumber">
            </div>                              
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht (optional)" id="message"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>

            <p>Woher kamen Sie? (optional)</p>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="source[]" value="Google"><p>Google</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="source[]" value="Facebook"><p>Facebook</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="source[]" value="Fernsehen"><p>Fernsehen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="source[]" value="Papiermedien"><p>Papiermedien</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="source[]" value="MuendlicheEmpfehlung"><p>Mündliche Empfehlung</label>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Nachricht senden</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the **PHP**:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   //empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   //empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$socialnumber = $_POST['socialnumber'];
$source = $_POST['source'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message\n\nAdresse:\n$address\n\nSocialnumber: $socialnumber\n\nKommt von: $source\n\n";
$headers = "From: noreply@daf-ausbildung.at\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

---

As you can see, I have inserted the name and the string-brackets in my name="source[]" in my checkboxes (As I found it in the other threads here on stackoverflow already).

Everything else in the contact form works and I get it via email (the name, socialnumber and all the other normal fields).

Just the values of the checkboxes don't get to my emails in the end.

Anyone has an idea why? Very thankful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['source']` is an `array`, try imploding it first

```
$source = implode(', ', $_POST['source']);
```